# App doesn't put Ampersands in Menu Items (wxPython)

Tags: python, wxpython, ampersand

The problem is simple but i still coudn't figure it out, when i run the code, the Ampersands don't appear in Menu Items. Why?!
I'm using Python 3.7.7 and wxPython 4.1.0, on Thonny v3.2.7.

```
import wx

def OnQuit(e):
    frame.Close()

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "wxPython Menu")
frame.SetSize(400, 300)

submenu1 = wx.Menu()
submenu1.Append(121, "Import Newsfeed List")
submenu1.Append(122, "Import Bookmarks")
submenu1.Append(123, "Import Mail")

menu1 = wx.Menu()
menu1.Append(10, "Open")
menu1.Append(11, "Save")
menu1.AppendSeparator()
menu1.AppendSubMenu(submenu1, "Import")
menu1.Append(13, "No Exit")

menu2 = wx.Menu()
menu2.Append(20, "Cut")
menu2.Append(21, "Copy")
menu2.Append(22, "Paste")
menu2.Enable(20, False)

menu3 = wx.Menu()
item = wx.MenuItem(menu3, 30, "&Quit\tCtrl+Q")
item.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("quit.png"))
menu3.Append(item)
menu3.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnQuit, id = 30)

menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
menuBar.Append(menu1, "&File")
menuBar.Append(menu2, "&Edit")
menuBar.Append(menu3, "&Extras")

frame.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
frame.Centre()
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SetItemLabel(self, label)
> Sets the label associated with the menu item.
>
> Note that if the ID of this menu item corresponds to a stock ID, then it is not  necessary to specify a label: wxWidgets will automatically use the stock item > label associated with that ID. See the constructor for more info.
>
> The label string for the normal menu items (not separators) may include the
> accelerator which can be used to activate the menu item from keyboard. An accelerator key can be specified using the ampersand & character. In order to embed an ampersand character in the menu item text, the ampersand must be doubled. **
> https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.MenuItem.html#wx-menuitem

The ampersand (&) is traditionally used as an accelerator on menu items.
If you press the `ALT` button your menus will (if defined with accelerators i.e. &File where the `&` next to `F` means pressing `F` will open the `File` menu) display with the accelerator letter underlined.
Press `F` and the `File` menu opens.
If menu items in the `File` menu have accelerators, they too will have a letter underlined, pressing that letter will select that menu item.

If you require an actual ampersand (&) without special meaning e.g. `Close & Quit`, you need to double the ampersand i.e. the items label should created as `Close && Quit` or `&Close && Quit` if the menu should not only display as `Close & Quit` but also respond when the user presses the letter `C`.